# Partial View using a Model, update it with Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, model, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a Partial View that uses a Model.
The Partial View is empty, except for a textbox and a button.

The user will type a value into the text box and click the button.

I want to use **Ajax** to take the value typed in the textbox, and perform a search on the database. Then with the data returned, update the Partial View with using the Model.

My code so far -

```
<input id="searchValue" type="text" />   
<input id="searchButton" type="submit" value="submit" />

<div>
@if(Model != null)
{
    foreach(var stuff in Model.ListOfStuff)
    {
        <li>@stuff.value</li>  
    }
}
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give an ID to your Result Div so that it will be easy for us to do it via jQuery later to update.

```
<div id="resultDiv">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Now addthis javascript code

```
$(function(){
  $("#searchButton").click(function(e){
     var key=$("#searchKey").val();
     $.getJSON("@Url.Action("search","Items")/"+key,function(data){
        var items="";
        $.each(data,function(index,item){
            items+="<li>"+item.Name+"</li>;
        });
        $("#resultDiv>ul").html(items);
     });
  });
});
```

Now we should have an action method which accepts the search key and return the Result in JSON format.

```
public ActionResult Search(string id)
{
  List<Product> productList=repo.GetSearchResultFromKey(id);
  return Json(productList,JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```

Assuming we have a viewmodel called `Product` like below and our `GetSearchResultFromKey` method returns a collection of Product classs from our search key.

```
public class Product
{
  public string Name { set;get;}
}
```

What we are doing here is, when user clicks on the search button, we get the search key and make a call to the search action method and the method will return the list of Product in `JSON` format. We are iterating through the items in the `JSON` Response and creating the `li` items and adding that to the `ul` element.

Make sure you have jQuery included in the page.

Answer (score 2):

This article will help you, just follow what they do and do the same applying their concepts to your code: [Updating Partial Views with Unobtrusive AJAX in MVC 3](http://geekswithblogs.net/blachniet/archive/2011/08/03/updating-partial-views-with-unobtrusive-ajax-in-mvc-3.aspx)